# could someone help me to understand concept of Pigeonhole sorting?

Tags: sorting

I have tried to understand the concept of pigeonhole sorting but i couldn't.
If someone can explain it to me in a easy way it will be very helpful to me!

Comment: Wiki article for [pigeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort).

Comment: have you tried google and youtube to know about this first

Answer (score 0):

[Pigeonhole algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort) is a sorting algorithm **used for the cases when the number of elements of input data and the number of possible key values** (i.e., freely chosen markers for them) **are approximately the same**, which basically means that every element is unique, or with relatively small number of repetitions within given list.

Steps for practical performing of pigeonhole algorithm are following:

1. Find minimum and maximum elements/values in the list.
2. Find range/size of the list using *max - min + 1* expression
3. Set up another, secondary list of initially empty "pigeonholes" with the size of the range given by step *2*.
4. Visit each element of the input list and put it in its pigeonhole of secondary list. An element of input list *arr[i]* is put in the pigeonhole of the secondary list of the index *a[i] - min*.
5. Iterate over the secondary/pigeonhole list in order (from first to last element), and put elements from non-empty pigeonholes back into the input list.

For graphical explanation of previously described steps watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVQz0kZNC64).

---

**Python implementation:**

```
def pigeonhole_sort(a):
    mi = min(a)
    size = max(a) - mi + 1
    holes = [0] * size
    for x in a:
        holes[x - mi] += 1
    i = 0
    for count in xrange(size):
        while holes[count] > 0:
            holes[count] -= 1
            a[i] = count + mi
            i += 1
```